# C# : How to get number of days from an object of DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

In C# ,How can i find the number of days in a month which resides in a DateTime object.

Ex :

```
DateTime objDate=new DateTime();
```

using the objDate, now i want to get the number of days of the current month. IS there any built-in function present in C# ?

Leap years also has to be taken care of

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int noOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(objDate.Year, objDate.Month);
```

Comment: *sigh*... I think I need to start just posting and not checking if it is correct :p

Answer (score 3):

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(objDate.Year, objDate.Month);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int daysInMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(objDate.Year, objDate.Month);
```

Comment: Missing a semi colon there mate.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;  
Double DaysInMonth = cultureInfo.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DateTime objDate = default(DateTime);
    objDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2009-02-05");

    Response.Write(DateTime.DaysInMonth(objDate.Year, objDate.Month));
```